# No window output while importing pandas and tkinter at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I've got this problem that I couldn't find any reason:No window output while importing pandas and tkinter at the same time. This is my code:

```
    from Tkinter import*
    import pandas
    App=Tk()
    source=Entry(App).pack()
    sortie=Entry(App).pack()
    Button(App, text='Traiter').pack() # a command will be insert here

    App.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works fine for me, are you sure tkinter doesn't open a window?  Remember that pandas can take up to a second to load before the rest of your script will run.

Comment: Yes. I'm sure, I'm using Wing IDE.

Answer (score 0):

```
from Tkinter import*
import pandas


App=Tk()
App.geometry("500x500")
source=Entry(App).pack()
sortie=Entry(App).pack()
Button(App, text='Traiter').pack() # a command will be insert here

App.mainloop()
```

When I add the geometry to give window size it works fine. try that

Comment: It doesn't work  for me. but when I ran it into the command-line it works well. May be there's a problem with my Wing IDE